# How to extract functions used in R package?

Tags: r

I have inadvertently over-ridden the package I created with a different function, saved it, and closed R Studio. Now, my R package contains an unintended function.

Thankfully, I did not install the package, so I still have the old package contents stored in my computer.

Is there a way to extract the function from the installed package? It's one long function. Not more than one function.

And, no, I do not have a backup, at least not the updated version.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what happened. However if you have an old version of the package, you can load the package and then just type the function name and its code will be sent to the terminal. You could then copy and paste that code.

Comment: What @JohnPaul commented is better but `functionBody()` also works (most of the times).

Comment: You might be automatically loading everything in the `.RData` file when you start a new R session.  Try `rm(name_of_function)` and see if you can use the package version afterwards.

Comment: Johns method did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

`View(package::function)`

Where `package` is the package you mentioned you had installed and `function` is the function you're looking to to inspect.

The important thing is to forego the parenthesis where you would normally have the function argument. This will open the function code for inspection.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the structure of a function by typing it's name in the console.

```
> sum
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

To get the function from a package, you can use the `::` operator

```
> dplyr::coalesce
function (x, ...) 
{
    values <- list(...)
    for (i in seq_along(values)) {
        x <- replace_with(x, is.na(x), values[[i]], paste0("Vector ", 
            i))
    }
    x
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```